# How to refresh GTM container manually?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've published the new version of container more than 12 hours ago, but I see 15 users in real-time report which still continue to send deleted events (timer). I've checked in preview mode and after publication: timer doesn't fire. I guess that page is open to several users and container is not updated there.

I know that GTM container refreshes every 12 hours (for apps or for websites too?)

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/TagManager.RefreshMode#enum-values

But I need to refresh container on site manually. I tried to find some examples in google, but unsuccessfully.
Please advise how to do it?